# routes to views break on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger

All routes except root_path break in prod., even though my `assert_select` tests all GREEN.

> The core of the problem was misconfigured Ngninx-Passenger. Initially I used a lot of default nginx.conf, and I failed
>   to track down exact error, it does not seems like it was     `passenger_document_root /var/www/html/mesite/public;`, since it is in my configs atm and all is working, maybe there was some other configs paths in the Nginx which I did not saw, since in essence I rebuild all my configs\config paths, including Nginx default conf., going from  **hurikhan77** example config.

Tests:

site_layout_test.rb

```
class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'me_site_static_html/me'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", resume_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", craft_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", dance_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", music_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
  end
end
```

---

me_site_static_html_controller_test.rb

```
class MeSiteStaticHtmlControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should get root" do
    get root_url 
    assert_response :success
  end

  def setup
    @base_site_name = "Пешеев Павел"
  end

  test "should get me" do
    get root_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "#{@base_site_name} | Я"
  end

  test "should get resume" do
    get resume_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "#{@base_site_name} | Резюме"
  end

  test "should get craft" do
    get craft_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "#{@base_site_name} | Навыки"
  end

  test "should get dance" do
    get dance_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "#{@base_site_name} | Танцует!"
  end

  test "should get music" do
    get music_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "#{@base_site_name} | Меломан"
  end

  test "should get contact" do
    get contact_path
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "#{@base_site_name} | Связаться"
  end

end
```

---

me_site_static_html_helper.rb (this and example view to give some context on variables)

```
module MeSiteStaticHtmlHelper
    # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title = '')
    base_title = "Пешеев Павел"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      base_title + " | " + page_title
    end
   end
end
```

view "contact.html.erb"

```
<% provide(:title, "Связаться") %>
...
```

---

routes.rb (UPD: there is some variation in the code, according to some answers, but they does no seem to make difference, result is the same. would like to read somewhere more about those differences)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'me_site_static_html#me'

  get '/me',     to: 'me_site_static_html#me'

  get '/resume'   => 'me_site_static_html#resume'

  get 'craft',    to:'me_site_static_html#craft'

  get '/dance',   to:'me_site_static_html#dance'

  get 'music'    =>  'me_site_static_html#music'

  get '/contact',   to: 'me_site_static_html#contact'

end
```

and just because I am baffled as to why this happens(again, test run green both in prod. and dev.) my one and only controller

```
class MeSiteStaticHtmlController < ApplicationController
  def me
  end

  def resume
  end

  def craft
  end

  def dance
  end

  def music
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

here is deployed result https://pesheevpavel.ru/
and, as you can see, both links to another static pages and just GET requests to corresponding pages do not work, somewhat baffled as to why. And all links look correct.
header html.erb looks like this:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <%= link_to "Пешеев Павел", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Я",        root_path %></div></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Резюме ",  resume_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Крафт ",   craft_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Танцы ",   dance_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Музыка ",  music_path %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

and it generates this html at root_path

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<a id="logo" href="/">Пешеев Павел</a>
<nav>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="/">Я</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resume">Резюме </a></li>
    <li><a href="/craft">Крафт </a></li>
    <li><a href="/dance">Танцы </a></li>
    <li><a href="/music">Музыка </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

relevent nginx config:

```
passenger_root /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
passenger_ruby /home/tech/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/wrappers/ruby;
passenger_instance_registry_dir /var/run/passenger-instreg;
root   /var/www/html/mesite/public;
passenger_document_root /var/www/html/mesite/public;
    passenger_enabled on;  
    rails_env production;


    index index.php index.html index.htm;

   location ~ ^/assets/ {
   expires 1y;
   add_header Cache-Control public; 
   add_header ETag "";
   break;
   }
```

---

error page (404)

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

---

rails -v
Rails 5.1.6

---

---

Logs:

```
 rake routes
 Prefix Verb URI Pattern        Controller#Action
     me GET  /me(.:format)      me_site_static_html#me
 resume GET  /resume(.:format)  me_site_static_html#resume
  craft GET  /craft(.:format)   me_site_static_html#craft
  dance GET  /dance(.:format)   me_site_static_html#dance
  music GET  /music(.:format)   me_site_static_html#music
contact GET  /contact(.:format) me_site_static_html#contact
   root GET  /                  me_site_static_html#me
```

---

production.rb `config.log_level = :debug`
production.log (no errors(?))

```
I, [2018-04-05T18:05:37.777489 #5609]  INFO -- : [8c046ad2-d911-487e-bd6c-00d6db966a75] Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.1ms)
I, [2018-04-05T18:05:38.909255 #5609]  INFO -- : [907e6cd0-2547-4bf4-b07c-9acb56668759] Started GET "/" for 79.173.103.210 at 2018-04-05 18:05:38 +0300
I, [2018-04-05T18:05:38.910120 #5609]  INFO -- : [907e6cd0-2547-4bf4-b07c-9acb56668759] Processing by MeSiteStaticHtmlController#me as HTML
I, [2018-04-05T18:05:38.911059 #5609]  INFO -- : [907e6cd0-2547-4bf4-b07c-9acb56668759]   Rendering me_site_static_html/me.html.erb within layouts/application
I, [2018-04-05T18:05:38.911620 #5609]  INFO -- : [907e6cd0-2547-4bf4-b07c-9acb56668759]   Rendered me_site_static_html/me.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
I, [2018-04-05T18:05:38.912188 #5609]  INFO -- : [907e6cd0-2547-4bf4-b07c-9acb56668759]   Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (0.4ms)
I, [2018-04-05T18:05:38.912362 #5609]  INFO -- : [907e6cd0-2547-4bf4-b07c-9acb56668759]   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
I, [2018-04-05T18:05:38.912861 #5609]  INFO -- : [907e6cd0-2547-4bf4-b07c-9acb56668759]   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.3ms)
I, [2018-04-05T18:05:38.913137 #5609]  INFO -- : [907e6cd0-2547-4bf4-b07c-9acb56668759]   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
I, [2018-04-05T18:05:38.913369 #5609]  INFO -- : [907e6cd0-2547-4bf4-b07c-9acb56668759] Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 2.5ms)
```

---

Nginx acces log on relevant GET

79.173.103.210 - - [05/Apr/2018:18:15:05 +0300] "GET /resume HTTP/1.1" 404 1722 "https://pesheevpavel.ru/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0" "-"

passenger online:

```
[ N 2018-04-05 17:57:26.0985 5440/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:984 ]: Passenger core online, PID 5440
```

aand someone trying to acces various admin pages, sql and whatnot(but still no err on my requests to, say, /resume)

```
[error] 15486#0: *243 "/usr/share/nginx/html/mysqlmanager/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 185.40.4.17, server: localhost, request: "GET /mysqlmanager/ HTTP/1.1", host: "46.229.212.97", referrer: "http://46.229.212.97/"
```

---

html err source: (it is definetly 404 page from public folder, one of the fiew things that are there, it is my understanding as it should be)

```
<body class="rails-default-error-page">
  <!-- This file lives in public/404.html -->
  <div class="dialog">
    <div>
      <h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>
      <p>You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.</p>
    </div>
    <p>If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

---

---

Found some weirdness in Mozilla log from the client side: apparently my webroot page is served by passenger +nginx:

```
Server  
nginx/1.12.2 + Phusion Passenger 5.2.3
Set-Cookie  
_mesite_session=MXRQaXlQNWpxbk…b9c; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Status  
200 OK
```

and my 404 are served by nginx alone:

```
Connection  
keep-alive
Content-Length  
1722
Content-Type    
text/html
Date    
Thu, 05 Apr 2018 15:53:41 GMT
ETag    
"5ac13601-6ba"
Server  
nginx/1.12.2
```

Comment: Hi - can you show us the message + stacktrace of the error that you are seeing? (from your logfiles)? You may need to change logging level to debug in order to see the stacktrace.

Comment: Also can you edit your question and add the html that is generated too? Links go stale, and we want stack overflow to be forever. So everything relevant should be in your question, rather than having to go somewhere else :)

Comment: Message - It is just plain old 404, just like when you try to include assets with usual html link tag in the code instead of <%= link_to %>.
I'll add full generated html, I just figured  post is already too long =)
Going to google now to learn about rails logging

Comment: **Also, I just had an idea: could it be due to switching to `pg` in prod, from `mysql` in dev?** I thought I configured postgresql correctly, and I dont actually use any model yet, and rails stopped spewing mistakes during rake env:producton, and I could log into pg console, so I figured I did it.

Comment: You should also add the request log and error message generated in der Rails log. And please run `rake routes` and show the output.

Comment: added all that - it does not even logs error in production.log despite  `config.log_level = :debug` -  am I missing something?

Comment: As @TarynEast said, please also post the HTML source of the generated 404 response. It currently doesn't look like this actually comes from the Rails app.

Comment: @ПавелПешеев The `production.log` you're showing is about `GET /` which works. Please show the relevant part of the log from a `GET /resume`.

Comment: Well that is a thing - there is no /resume GET 's in production log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you write that you don't see `GET /resume` when you try to access `/resume` on your production server but instead you see `GET /`, I assume your nginx configuration to be broken.

Your problem may be with using `passenger_document_root` - you shouldn't probably use it for your deployment (it's only used if deploying apps into sub directories).

Here's a working example I am using, please adapt to your setup (this is a Rails/Passenger-only nginx instance):

Main configuration:

```
# cat nginx.conf                                                                                                                                                                                        
user nginx nginx;                                                                                                                                                                                                     
worker_processes 4;                                                                                                                                                                                                   

events {                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        worker_connections 1024;                                                                                                                                                                                      
        use epoll;                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

http {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        client_header_timeout 10m;
        client_body_timeout 10m;
        send_timeout 10m;

        connection_pool_size 256;
        client_header_buffer_size 1k;
        large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;
        request_pool_size 4k;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1100;
        gzip_buffers 4 8k;
        gzip_types text/plain;

        output_buffers 1 32k;
        postpone_output 1460;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;

        keepalive_timeout 75 20;

        ignore_invalid_headers on;

        index index.html;

        client_max_body_size 100m;

        passenger_root /usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
        passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;
        passenger_max_pool_size 50;
        passenger_pool_idle_time 1200;
        passenger_max_instances_per_app 20;
        passenger_max_requests 1000;

        include sites.d/*.conf;
}
```

General settings:

```
# cat settings.d/expire-statics.conf
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
}
```

Site configuration:

```
# cat sites.d/aaaa.bbbbb.de.conf
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name aaaa.bbbbb.de;
        include settings.d/expire-statics.conf;

        root /home/kakra/rails-apps/aaaa/production/current/public;
        rails_env production;
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_min_instances 5;
}
```

Comment: same result. For better tracking it is now `get 'music' =>  'me_site_static_html#music'

  get '/resume' => 'me_site_static_html#resume'


  get 'craft', to:'me_site_static_html#craft'
 get '/dance', to:'me_site_static_html#dance'`
 Would like to know more about this though: are /me and me equivalent or not?

Comment: It is definetly generates same html code in the end:
`<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
     <a id="logo" href="/">Пешеев Павел</a>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/">Я</a></li>
            <li><a href="/resume">Резюме </a></li>
            <li><a href="/craft">Крафт </a></li>
   <li><a href="/dance">Танцы </a></li>
   <li><a href="/music">Музыка </a></li>
          </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>`

Comment: Please edit your original post instead of pasting answers randomly into comments.

Comment: Is it worth to post this? Cause it did nothing, and it seems to generate same html, aand there  is no explanation as to why this can make a difference. Seems just irrelevant. Did edited original post to mirrow changes. =))

Comment: Thanks a LOT! You config + simple ssl configs worked, now on to slowly working through nginx configs to find out what breaks it. Will prob. post answer. YOu helped me a lot, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I think it is due to `passenger_document_root` as I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: If you clean up your question post to reflect the core problem and analysis, I'll upvote your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'me_site_static_html#me'

  get '/me',        to: 'me_site_static_html#me'

  get '/resume',    to: 'me_site_static_html#resume'

  get '/craft',     to: 'me_site_static_html#craft'

  get '/dance',     to: 'me_site_static_html#dance'

  get '/music',     to: 'me_site_static_html#music'

  get '/contact',   to: 'me_site_static_html#contact'

end
```

Try that:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'me_site_static_html#me'

  get 'me' => 'me_site_static_html#me'

  get 'resume' => 'me_site_static_html#resume'

  get 'craft' => 'me_site_static_html#craft'

  get 'dance' => 'me_site_static_html#dance'

  get 'music' => 'me_site_static_html#music'

  get 'contact' => 'me_site_static_html#contact'

end
```

Comment: I tried it, same result, my understanding it is effectively synonyms (correct me, if I am wrong, but in ether case we just transfer some parameters to rails object, as some sort of another collection of objects, hence hashrocket).I posted here `,   to: ` instead of hash rocket for clarity.As of now, in the code, it is actually ` get '/me' => 'me_site_static_html#me'
  get '/contact' =>  'me_site_static_html#contact'